# Как посмотреть процесс экспорта mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, linux, innodb

БД весит порядка 80 ГБ, при автоматическом создании бекапа занимает ~1час 30мин. Экспорт запускал командой `mysqldump -uroot -p mydatabase > /home/mydatabase.sql`, соединение с сервером через PuTYY оборвалось. Как теперь посмотреть идет ли процесс экспорта? В конечной директории размер файла показывает `0`.
Если смотреть активные процессы через `top | grep mysql`, то там только `17224 root      20   0 5848m 582m 7416 S  0.3  2.6   0:09.30 mysqld`

Версии: `InnoDB ver 14.14l`, `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6`

Comment: Видимо не идёт, раз top-grep ничего не показал

Comment: Запускать надо в фоне, пользуясь `screen ` или подобными.

Comment: Процесс `mysqldump` был привязан к процессу оболочки (bash), который в свою очередь был привязан к экземпляру `sshd`. После обрыва соединения процесс `sshd` завершил работу, остановив дочерний процесс оболочки (bash), а завершение процесса оболочки, убило дочерний процесс mysqldump. Вывод: подобные вещи надо запускать в бэкграунде (cron, &), либо через мультиплексоры (screen, tmux) .

Comment: А может быть `sshd` настроен так, что процесс уже успешно самостоятельно завершился, а от оболочки остался призрак... но в любом случае он уже не идёт...